# OneNote cannot open onepkg file from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, onenote

I am using OneNote 2010 with SharePoint 2013. So far, it has been working fine when I sync a notebook/sections/pages. However, I am having trouble opening a .onepkg file when it is stored in SharePoint 2013.

I have tried the following two things and neither work:

1. Created a document library that uses the OneNote 2010 Notebook document template (advanced settings when you add a document library). When you go to the File ribbon and click on **New Document**, it tries to open OneNote 2010 with the OneNote template but gives me an error.
2. Create a .onepkg notebook in OneNote. The file opens when it is located on my local hard drive. However, the moment I move it to SharePoint and try to open it it gives me an error.

The error is always the same: **OneNote cannot open the specified location: onenote: https://*SharePoint Document Library location*/template.onepkg.**

Anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: have you tried this https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/172/t/11239

Comment: Yes, I can open the onepkg in OneNote and then sync it back to SharePoint. I figured since the .onepkg is a template in a OneNote content type already in SP, I can just open it from SP to OneNote. Looks like a design flaw in SP.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Found the solution. You cannot extract a .onepkg from Sharepoint directly. Save it to your desktop. Open it from there and when prompted for the extract destination, then specify your Sharepoint folder and it will "unzip it" there!

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint can't extract OneNote package. You need to sync the One note to SharePoint.

You check the article.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/onenote-onepkg-files-failing-to-load-and-export/baf63647-9ad2-44a4-908b-e907f044bc28